# Binding values dynamically to a toggle button in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, togglebutton

I'm creating a toggle button to which I want to bind a select event. I've created the button, but I have no clue of how to bind the values to it and make it work like a select button. Can someone give me some clue or some examples related to it, so that I can try that out and learn some thing?

My requirement is I've to bind the select event to it and make it work like a select button.

This is how I've created the button:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-6">Tax Value</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-btn">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle align-right" id="tax_toggle" name="tax_toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Tax <span class="caret"></span></button>
                            </div>
                            <input type="text" id="invoice_request_tax_value" name="invoice_request_tax_value" class="form-control" placeholder="Tax Value" required="required" readonly="readonly">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-12" id="invoice_request_tax_value_label">Tax Value - Nil</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by select button? <select> is used for dropdown as far as I know. [select](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp)

Comment: I want my toggle button to work like select. When I click the button, it should display options like how the <select> shows and I should choose from it.

Comment: Why you are not using the <select> tag itself? It will work the way you want.

Comment: My requirement is like that. That's why.

Comment: Instead of using <button> try creating custom dropdown using <div> and <span>, since you don't want to use <select>.

Comment: Can you try answering this? "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37227606/designing-a-select-drop-down?noredirect=1#comment61985145_37227606", because this is how I got when I tried using select.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112113/discussion-between-titi23-and-duddosai).

Answer (score 0):

Try using [knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/introduction.html). 
This is what I am using to do the kind of action you want (binding value dynamically)

[foreach-binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html) is the solution to your problem.

Also [options-binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html) can be used, which you can use with select tag only.

See If you can use knockout.

Answer (score 0):

create your observables then bind them per slide/toggle then u can adjust this example such that when toggled the select value in your dropdown becomes yourdropdown.selectedText (javascript) , you will notice which may seem like commented code but are actually conditional statements in ko

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: yourObservableArray">
    <tr data-bind="attr: { 'id': description }">
    <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;">
      <label data-bind="text: description"></label>
     </td>
   <td class="td-actions" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;">
  <input type="text" class="input-mini" data-bind="value: amount">
 <input type="hidden" class="input-mini" data-bind="attr: { 'id': 'DC_' + description }, value: Totalcost">
  </td>
     <td class="toggle-soft">
    <!-- ko if: description == 'Data' -->
   <div id="slider" class="toggle floatright" onclick="toggleCOS()"></div>
                                                                <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" class="checkbx" id="cos_data" style="display: none;">
  </div>
     <!-- /ko -->
      <!-- ko if: description != 'Data' -->
       Cost
       <!-- /ko -->
           </td>
                </tr>
           </tbody>
```